# Why do i get locked out of my own database account on hostinger?

Tags: php, mysql

The line I'm trying to use is :

```
use foodorder;
```

I get a reply specifying:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'u548475702_foody'@'localhost' to database 'foodorder'

P.S. I'm not using the database with a hostname of localhost, I'm using `mysql.hostinger.in` as specified in their website.

My php code is:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.in','u548475702_foody','not the actual password','u548475702_food')
        or die("Error connecting to database!");
```

[image: DB Info]

I've also ensured that the associated user has all the required permissions:

[image: User Permissions]

So why am I still getting this message?

Comment: have you tired `localhost` instead of `mysql.hostinger.in` - Last time I checked, Hostinger used localhost DNS. Also, `use foodorder;` declares the use of a namespace inherited by a `require`/`include` not a database

Comment: But they specifically mention the hostname to be mysql.hostinger.in as shown in the picture!

Comment: This isn't exactly a **programming issue**, contact your hosting provider if the problem consists. You have either incorrectly typed your password or their service is causing you issue because there is nothing wrong with your **code**.

Comment: @KDOT Coincidentally this is also the same error I get when I try to run a SQL query using their own PHPMyAdmin on their site. Any ideas?

Comment: contact your hosting providers

Comment: In the privilege table you only show the grant for *u54…foody@mysql.hostinger.in*, but the error message clearly says that the connection is attempted as *u54…foody@localhost*, which is a completely different ACL entry. You should either add the latter one in addition to the former, or just change the allowed host name to *localhost*.